# Sending Javascript in Shiny

Tags: javascript, r, shiny

I am trying to change an inputs on Shiny using JS with an input from the server (so the value can be conditional).
In this example I've fixed the value to 'NJ' but at the end id like this value to be dynamic. The end result I am trying to achieve is to get the dropdown menu to change to a value (here 'NJ') when the button is clicked. Working example below.

My JS knowledge is pretty light and most of it has come from reading the R documentation, such as the doc below.

https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/communicating-with-js.html

```
library("shiny")

ui <- fluidPage(

        tags$script("Shiny.addCustomMessageHandler('change_sel', function(x){
                     Shiny.setInputValue('state', x,{priority: 'event'});
                });")
    ,
    column(6,
           selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                        c("NY", "NJ", "CT")
           ),
           column(6,
                  actionButton("but1", "Change to NJ"
                  )

               )))

server <- function(input, output, session) {
    observeEvent(input$but1, {
        session$sendCustomMessage("change_sel", "NJ")
    })

    observe(print(input$state))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: Since you are using shiny input components, I would recommend using the `updateSelectInput` function (available in the Shiny pkg). Setting input values through JS works best for custom input components (i.e., non-shiny elements). If you are using custom components, you can modify a component's states via `session$sendInputMessage` (in R) and `receiveInputMessage` in a custom input binding.

Comment: Thanks @dcruvolo, could you expand on how receiveInputMessage would be used? The example is just using Shiny components but my ends goal is a workaround for a bs4Dash component.

Comment: Hey @Ben - see my reply below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using shiny input components and would like to update the value of an input element by some other means (e.g., button click), then use one of the `update-` functions (available in the shiny package). However, it is unlikely that these update functions will work (or are even available) for non-Shiny widgets.

One alternative is to create a custom input binding where data is sent between Shiny and the client. This approach is best for custom input components or for creating wrappers around existing component libraries (non-R/Shiny packages). (For more information, checkout the following RStudio guides *Building Custom Input Objects* and *How to create custom input bindings*. I won't go into detail here about input bindings as it would make for a long answer).

Messages can be sent from Shiny to the client using `session$sendInputMessage()`. In the input binding (written using jQuery; vanilla JS won't work), use the `receiveInputMessage` method to retrieve and respond to the data. Using the example provided in your question, I provided a demo on how to update a custom select input widget in response to a button click.

Let me know if you have any questions!

```r
library(shiny)

ui <- tagList(
    tags$main(
        tags$h1("Receive Message Input"),
        tags$label(
            `for` = "state",
            "Select a State"
        ),
        tags$select(
            id = "state",
            class = "select__input",
            tags$option(value = "NONE", "--- Select ---"),
            tags$option(value = "NY", "New York"),
            tags$option(value = "NJ", "New Jersey"),
            tags$option(value = "CT", "Connecticut")
        ),
        tags$button(
            id = "state_ny",
            class = "shiny-bound-input action-button",
            "Select New York"
        ),
        tags$button(
            id = "state_nj",
            class = "shiny-bound-input action-button",
            "Select New Jersey"
        ),
        tags$button(
            id = "state_reset",
            class = "shiny-bound-input action-button",
            "Reset"
        )
    ),
    tags$script(
        type = "text/javascript",
        HTML(
            "const myCustomBinding = new Shiny.InputBinding();",
            "$.extend(myCustomBinding, {
                find = function(scope) {
                    return $(scope).find('.select__input');
                },
                getValue = function(el) {
                    return $(scope).value;
                },
                subscribe = function(el, callback) {
                    $(el).on('change', function(e) {
                        callback();
                    });
                },
                receiveInputMessage = function(el, message) {
                    if (message.type === 'update') {
                        $(el).value = data.value
                    }
                },
                unsubscribe = function(el) {
                    $(el).off('myCustomBinding');
                }
            });",
            "Shiny.inputBindings.register(myCustomBinding);"
        )
    )
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {

    # server-side function for sending data for use in `receiveInputMessage`
    setSelectValue <- function(inputId, value) {
        session$sendInputMessage(
            inputId = inputId,
            message = list(
                type = "update",
                value = value
            )
        )
    }

    # onClick Events
    observeEvent(input$state_ny, setSelectValue("state", "NY"))
    observeEvent(input$state_nj, setSelectValue("state", "NJ"))
    observeEvent(input$state_reset, setSelectValue("state", "NONE"))

    observe(print(input$state))
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

Comment: thank you. I was completely unaware of how to add the JS side of the interaction and this makes it really clear. The version I needed working is now working thanks to this and i've gotten over the first step in learning JS implementation! thanks.